# Javascript find replace content that has "/" in the search string

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript code which finds and replaces all instances of a value on a page. I am working with a CMS so unfortunately I need to work around lack of flexibility with the base HTML.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/VALUE/g, new_value);
```

I want to find a replace a url link using the same process. How do I take into account for the"/" in the search and replace strings?

Example:

```
find_str = "www.mysite.com/folder";
replace_str = "app.mysite.com/page";
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/find_str/g, replace_str);
```

Comment: Use `RegExp` constructor. **Code:** `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(find_str, 'g'), replace_str);`

Comment: Tushar’s comment is correct. But replacing the entire content of the `body` will yield several other problems. I would just replace the `href` attributes of the links individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your replies. I have taken advice from both and changed my code as follows:

```
jQuery('a[href="tttps://www.mysite.com/folder"]').attr("href", "tttps://app.mysite.com/page");
```

PS: I cannot add `https://` to the above as it will not let me save, so I added `tttps://` instead.

Comment: Glad that has worked, but when you can use jQuery, add the tag to the question or mention it.